# Is there an analogue of Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem, but for $\mathrm{On}$?

Tags: set-theory

From wikipedia:

> Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem shows that $\Pi^1_2$ and $\Sigma^1_2$
>   sentences in the analytical hierarchy are absolute between a model $V$
>   of ZF and the constructible universe $L$ of the model, when interpreted
>   as statements about the natural numbers in each model.

**Question.** Is there an "ordinal" version of the arithmetical and/or analytic hierarchies such that an analogue of Shoenfield absoluteness can be proven for that hierarchy? (With $\omega$ replaced by $\mathrm{On}$). My gut feeling is that we have to choose our language very carefully, in order to block $\aleph_1$ and/or $\beth_1$ from being definable by formulae somewhere in the hierarchy.

Comment: Just to clarify: a $\Pi^1_2$ sentence is of the form $(\forall X \in 2^\omega) (\exists Y \in 2^\omega)\  \varphi(x,y)$ where $\varphi$ is a quantifier-free formula in the language of arithmetic.  I assume you are suggesting looking at sentences of the form $(\forall X \in 2^\mathrm{On}) (\exists Y \in 2^\mathrm{On})\ \varphi(x,y)$ where $\varphi$ is a quantifier-free formula in the "language of ordinal arithmetic" suitably defined.  Is this correct?

Comment: To continue my last comment, this may be a silly question, but is there even a good way to express the quantifier $(\exists Y \in 2^\mathrm{On})$?  It seems to me that $2^\mathrm{On}$ is too big to be a proper class.  (For example, replacement is an axiom schema since one can't quantify over all class functions in a single sentence.)

Comment: @JasonRute, yes. I don't know how to express such a quantifier within the language of ZFC, but one option would be to work with set-sized transitive models of ZFC. Another would be to using second-order ZFC with Henkin semantics. A third option would be to just dilute the theorem we're trying to prove, and stick to first-order stuff.

Comment: Perhaps a more modest question is: Is there an analog of Shoenfield's (or even Mostowski's) absoluteness theorem for $2^{\kappa}$ where $\omega<\kappa$ (perhaps under additional assumptions)? I know that Sy Friedman and others have been working recently on generalized descriptive set theory, but I don't think this question was addressed yet (it sure seems like an interesting one to me).

Comment: @Haim: How would you state this absoluteness in terms of quantifiers, logic and limitations? E.g., quantifiers range on ordinals below $\kappa$ as first order and subsets of $\kappa$ for second order, in $\cal L_{\kappa\kappa}$ and the limitations would be $\Sigma_2^1$. Or something else?

Comment: @Haim: And as/more importantly, which structure should satisfy the supposedly absolute statements?

Comment: Asaf, this is how I think about this problem (at least for the $\Sigma_1^1$ case): You may regard generalized analytic sets as projections of closed sets. Now the question is whether we can find a reasonable tree representation for such sets as in the case of $\kappa=\omega$, and then we would like to have some absoluteness theorems about the existence of $\kappa$-branches (obviously this is not as simple as the original case). Perhaps we need some general absoluteness theorems for infinitary logics, I don't know.

Comment: @Haim: I think that there has been work in this aspect. I recall a couple of talks by Sy Friedman and his many collaborators on the topic. I might be remembering *very* wrong, though. If you'll grace us with your presence on Wednesday we can have a few words on the topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the solution lies in the Levy absoluteness theorem.

We define the Levy hierarchy of formulas as follows.

1. $\Sigma_0,\Pi_0,\Delta_0$ are formulas in the language of set theory which only have bounded quantifiers.
2. $\Sigma_{n+1}$ formulas equivalent to formulas of the form $\exists x\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is $\Pi_n$; and similarly $\Pi_{n+1}$ are formulas equivalent to $\forall x\varphi$ where $\varphi$ is $\Sigma_n$.
3. $\Delta_n$ are formulas which are both $\Sigma_n$ and $\Pi_n$.

Now we have that if $M$ is a transitive class (set or otherwise), then $\Delta_0$ formulas are absolute between $M$ and $V$ (as long as $M$ includes all the parameters). Next we have that $\Sigma_1$ formulas are upwards absolute and $\Pi_1$ formulas are downwards absolute, so $\Delta_1$ formulas are absolute.

Comment: The last sentence is just wrong. For instance, CH is $\Delta_2$, but not upwards absolute.

Comment: Err, yes. You're right. I have no idea why that sentence entered the answer! :|

Comment: It appears though that Boolean combinations of $\Sigma_1$ *sentences* (but not formulas with arbitrary parameters) are absolute, the reason being that a $\Sigma_1$ sentence is equivalent to the existence of its countable transitive model, and that’s a $\Sigma^1_2$ statement.

Comment: @Emil: Yes, I wanted to add that at first, but for some reason (which I cannot recall through these two hours) decided against this. Note that this absoluteness requires $\sf DC$ to hold in $V$, since it is needed for the existence of the countable transitive model (although there might be a way to go around that, or weaken the general requirement of $\sf DC$).

Comment: @Emil: By the way, as phrased above, $\Sigma_1$ statements are closed under conjunction and disjunction.

Comment: Can we get an absoluteness theorem higher than $\Delta_1$ by start off the recursion as follows? Define that $Σ_0,Π_0$ and $Δ_0$ consist of all formulae in the language of set theory bounded by *ordinals.*

Comment: What exactly do you mean bounded by ordinals? I ask because I have defined the notion of "ordinal bounded" quantifier to mean that the quantified variable is a set of finite tuples of ordinals.

Comment: I don't know man, upon further reflection my suggestion really makes no sense. When you say "I ask because I have defined..." you mean in your own work, right?

Comment: @user18921: Yes, in my own work, in a recent work too. It should be pointed out that the Shoenfield theorem talks about quantifying over sets of integers, which is the same as talking about sets of tuples of integers; which is why I asked -- the natural extension would be sets of tuples of ordinals.