# On statistical bases in Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, open-problems

Let $K$ be a subset of the positive integers $\mathbb{N}$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $K_{n}$ denotes the set $\{k\in K: k\leq n\}$ and $|K_{n}|$ denotes the number of the elements in $K_{n}$. The natural density of $K$ is defined by $$\delta(K)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|K_{n}|}{n}.$$
A sequence $(x_{k})_{k}$ in a Banach space $X$ is said to be norm statistically convergent to $x\in X$ if $\delta(\{k\in \mathbb{N}:\|x_{k}-x\|\geq \epsilon\})=0$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

It is natural to define a series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_{k}$ to be norm statistically convergent to $x\in X$ by $(s_{n})_{n}=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k})_{n}$ to be norm statistically convergent to $x$.

We say that a sequence $(x_{k})_{k}$ in a Banach space $X$ is a statistical basis for $X$ if, for each $x\in X$, there exists a unique $(a_{k})_{k}$ such that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}x_{k}$ norm statistically convergent to $x$.

Clearly, statistical basis is a generalization of the notion of Schauder basis.

Question: For each $n$, we can define a linear functional $f_{n}$ in $X$ by $f_{n}(x)=a_{n}$. If $(x_{k})_{k}$ is a Schauder basis, we know that $f_{n}$ is continuous. However, if $(x_{k})_{k}$ is a statistical basis for $X$, is $f_{n}$ continuous?

Comment: what is an example of a statistical basis which is not a Schauder basis?

Comment: Example 1 on page 254 in http://bit.ly/2yil4fa gives a statistical M-basis, which is not a Schauder basis.However, the coordinate functionals in that basis are continuous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit 26.04.2022**. The problem is now solved; please see [my other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359434/15129).

---

This is an open problem due to Vladimir Kadets. I would not expect an easy answer here. The problem with statistical convergence is that this filter is not countably generated (in which case these functionals would be continuous).

A more general question is also open. Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on $\mathbb N$. Say that a sequence $(e_n)$ in a Banach space $X$ is an $\mathcal F$*-basis* if every element $x\in X$ has a unique expansion as $$\mathcal{F}-\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n e_k^*(x)e_k.$$
Are the linear functionals $(e_n^*)$ continuous?

The only positive result so far is a theorem of Kochanek which says that the answer is yes when $\mathcal F$ is generated by less than $\mathfrak p$ elements (here $\mathfrak p$ denotes the pseudo-intersection number; see [this entry](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2017/09/19/two-infinities-that-are-surprisingly-equal/#more-6359) on T. Gowers' blog for more details).

> T. Kochanek, [ℱ-bases with brackets and with individual brackets in Banach spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.3097), *Studia Math.* **211** (2012), 259-268.

---

For the statistical convergence, one may suggest a meta-proof. The definition of statistical convergence does not involve (full) Axiom of Choice. There are models of ZF+DC where all linear functionals on Banach spaces are continuous hence you cannot have a constructible counterexample, should it exist.

Comment: You say that this is an open problem due to Vladimir Kadets. Could you tell me in which paper Vladimir Kadets posed this problem?

Comment: Are there any papers about statistical bases in Banach spaces? Could you tell me any reference about statistical bases? I am interested in it.

Comment: @DongyangChen all relevant information is contained on the first page of the above-linked paper by Kochanek.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit 26.04.2022**. The problem has been recently solved in ZFC. [arxiv.org/abs/2203.15123](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.15123).

---

In a recent note with J. Swaczyna ([arXiv:2005.04873](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.04873)), we proved that assuming the existence of certain large cardinals (for example, the existence of a [super-compact cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercompact_cardinal)) that filter bases whose underlying filter is a projective subset of the Cantor set, have continuous coordinate functionals. The role of large cardinals is to make the heuristic proof I outlined in my other answer work.

The filter of statistical convergence is actually $F_{\sigma \delta}$ (hence Borel, hence projective), so in a theory stronger than ZFC, the answer to your question is affirmative. We still expect that, at least for Borel filters, the question about continuity of coordinate functionals should have a positive answer in ZFC. However, our proof method does not give a chance to invoke [Schoenfield's absoluteness theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168053/is-there-an-analogue-of-shoenfields-absoluteness-theorem-but-for-mathrmon) in that context.

Comment: Do you use some determinacy?

Comment: @MonroeEskew, yes, in fact, we wanted to prove this under PD, but got lost in some technicalities.